Operational amplifier

Hello everyone!
I have this exercise to solve and I don't know how!
This is an ideal operational amplifier and from the theory I think V+ = V- and i+ = i- = 0
The first thing I did and I think it is correct is to convert the current source to the equivalent voltage, by connecting the resistor 5Ω in series. So instead of 1A current source there will be a voltage source 5V in series with the resistor 5Ω.

I need to find V0 and I0
Any help appreciated!!
Thanks in advance!!

In OpAmp circuits with multiple generators, it is convenient to apply the principle of superposition of effects to determine the output voltage. In practice, you have to analyze the circuit by leaving only one generator active while canceling the effect of the other generators. At the end, the effects found are algebraically added. (A current generator is deactivated by opening the circuit, while an independent voltage generator is deactivated by replacing it with a short circuit).

I have converted the current generator to voltage source as shown in the image above. I know that I should apply the superposition law but I do not know how. Can you please provide a solution so I can study it? Thank you very much in advance and for the response!!!

You must proceed as I said previously always considering the virtual short circuit between V+ and V-- valid.

Do I need to calculate V- and V+ and calculate V- = V+?

Here's an approach not often taught, but it does illustrate another way to treat op-amps. First let me redraw the circuit with some extra annotations to help:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
As you already pointed out:

By op-amp action with negative feedback: $$V_P=V_Q$$

Source I1 and resistor R1 can be replaced by their Thevenin equivalent:



simulate this circuit
Since the op-amp inputs sink or source no current, by KCL I can see that current is equal through R3, R4 and R5. I'll call that current \$I\$.
One more thing is clear; since current in R2 is zero, the potential difference between nodes A and P must also be zero, by Ohm's law. Therefore
$$ V_A = V_P = V_Q $$
Here's the trick. We can treat the op-amp as a voltage source, producing some potential at its output, node OUT. Since the inputs don't source or sink any current, from the perspective of anything connected to those inputs, it's as if the op-amp isn't even there. So, let's draw that very scenario:

simulate this circuit
Source V3 now represents the op-amp output, and our goal is to find its voltage. Obviously R2 is now redundant, and can be removed, and the circuit becomes:

simulate this circuit
This is pretty trivial to solve for \$V_{OUT}\$, but don't forget, as we established earlier:
$$ V_A = V_Q $$
You've got it from here.

You can ignore the 2Ω resistor since the input current is zero. Call the voltage at the inputs (which will be equal at balance) Vx.
Now you can find the current through the 100Ω resistor and therefore the difference between Vx and Vo. The current through the 100Ω resistor has the same magnitude as Io since the input currents are zero.
Now to find Vo you know that the same current must go through the 100Ω resistor that goes through the 5Ω Thevenin equivalent resistor, so you can find Vx and thence Vo.

Thank you very much for the response! I added the new circuit after converting the current source to voltage source. From this point I took the superposition principle to calculate V0 having on the 20V source and then having on the 5V source. Can you please solve the problem so I can study the solution? I do not know how to solve it. Thanks!!

Also do I need to calculate V- and V+ and solve the V- = V+?

Start off by ignoring the current source, by assuming the voltage at current source output is zero.  The resulting circuit should look very familiar to you.
Hint: inverting amplifier.
Solve that circuit, then add the Thevinan equivalent of the current source to it (which you have already done).

Thank you very much for the response! I added the new circuit after converting the current source to voltage source. From this point I took the superposition principle to calculate V0 having on the 20V source and then having on the 5V source.
Can you please solve the problem so I can study the solution? I do not know how to solve it. Thanks!!

First, attempt your own solution using the method in Spehro's answer.

Well, let's analyze the circuit:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
We know, when working with an ideal opamp, that:
$$\text{I}_-=\text{I}_+=0\space\text{A}\tag1$$
$$\text{V}_-=\text{V}_+\tag2$$
So, we can conclude that:
$$\text{I}_3=\text{I}_4=\text{I}_0\tag3$$
Using KCL, we can see that:
$$\text{I}=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_3\tag4$$
Using Ohm's law we get:
$$\text{I}_1=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\tag5$$
$$\text{I}_+=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_-}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\tag6$$
$$\text{I}_3=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-\text{V}_+}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}\tag7$$
$$\text{I}_4=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_+-\text{V}_\text{o}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}\tag8$$
